# Flutter - How to cancel pointer up event

Tags: flutter

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Listener-class.html

In this example if the pointer is released outside the blue container it counts as a release. How to cancel the pointer event when the pointer reaches outside the blue container? I have tried ignore pointer and absorb pointer with my specific use case in which I have two children in a column and the listener is attached to the second one , but the first one is also emitting pointer up event. I want the functionality of PointerUpEvent as I want to get the localposition so onPanEnd of GestureDetector doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping Listener with LayoutBuilder and passing constraints from LayoutBuilder and details from PointerUpEvent can be used to validate if the touch is inside the bounds.

```
bool _isInsideBox(BoxConstraints constraints, PointerUpEvent details) {
    return details.localPosition.dx >= 0.0 &&
    details.localPosition.dy >= 0.0 &&
    details.localPosition.dx <= constraints.maxWidth &&
    details.localPosition.dy <= constraints.maxHeight;
}
```

Then simply call the function inside onPointerUp

```
void _onPointerUp(PointerUpEvent details) {
   if(_isInsideBox(constraints,details)){
     //do something
    }
   else{
    // do nothing
    }
}
```

The more concrete solution is given by @Zolicious

Comment: this is the better approach than anything i guess

Comment: What example have you used to test this code? If it works I can mark it as the solution

Comment: i didnt test this, i assumed u tested this, "looks" like a better approach

Answer (score 2):

Make a method that validates whether the pointer is outside the child or not. Then you can condition it inside your onTapUp event.

Something like this:

Get the **Size** of your child

```
final RenderBox childRenderBox = _childKey.currentContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
final Size childSize = childRenderBox.size;
```

Convert the child's local coordinate sytem to the global coordinate system in logical pixels

```
final Offset childPosition = childRenderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
```

Check whether the touchPosition(Pointer) is outside of the child or box

```
return touchPosition.dx < childPosition.dx ||
    touchPosition.dx > childPosition.dx + childSize.width ||
    touchPosition.dy < childPosition.dy ||
    touchPosition.dy > childPosition.dy + childSize.height;
```

Finally, you have a method that checks whether the pointer is outside or not.

```
bool _isOutsideChildBox(Offset touchPosition) {
final RenderBox childRenderBox =
    _childKey.currentContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
final Size childSize = childRenderBox.size;
final Offset childPosition = childRenderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);

return touchPosition.dx < childPosition.dx ||
    touchPosition.dx > childPosition.dx + childSize.width ||
    touchPosition.dy < childPosition.dy ||
    touchPosition.dy > childPosition.dy + childSize.height;
}
```

Now on your onTapUp event check whether the touch's position is outside or not then do something out of it.

```
void _onTapUp(PointerUpEvent event) {
    if(_isOutSideChildBox(event.position)){
      dont emit release...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello , great answer thank you, I am just trying it! Can I know if wrapping the child in the layout builder to get a context is fine as opposed to using a key?

Answer (score 1):

If someone doesn't want make position, constraints and render objects, etc. Use this simple code.
Instantiate a bool:

```
    bool move = false;
```

Use like this:

```
    onPointerMove: (_){
              moved = true;
            },
    OnPointerUp: (_) {
              If (! moved) {do this;}
            },
    OnPointerDown: (_) {
              SetState (() {
                _onCardTapped = !_onCardTapped;
                moved = false;
              });
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

an easier approach would be to still use the GestureDetector, if you are looking for local position when the pan ends, use `onPanEnd()` with `onPanUpdate()`

when pan ends use the last `DragUpdateDetails` provided by onPanUpdate to get the position

Comment: If the pointer is leaving the child I want to get the last successful PointerUp values but using GestureDetector onPanUpdate continuously updates the values which isnot necessary when the pointer leaves the child I want to cancel the whole event

Comment: I tried mouse region it doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: pan update happens only when the pointer is down, if you are asking for last pointer location when the it was still inside the bounds of the box, use the above approach with MouseRegion

Comment: I will try panUpdate but MouseRegion doesnot seem to work for me.

Comment: i tried on the simulator, the mouse region didnt work

Comment: Yes the onExit didn't get called.

Comment: nope, tested on iphone simulator and an android device, no onEnter / onExit called